# Groups of buttons in angular-material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Can I create the same functionality
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ (chapter: Buttons (ui.bootstrap.buttons)

using angular-material?

Angular-material has radio-button directive but I can’t use it because I don’t want “the dot” on the left side of the label.

Angular-material has also select directive but it is not the same functionality.

Do I have another options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can get the same functionality.

Plunk : [Done here](http://plnkr.co/edit/p21PHfweIgJTi4uOsMtZ?p=preview)

Script :

```
 var app=angular.module('myApp',['ngMaterial'])
   .config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
     $mdThemingProvider.theme('primary')
    .primaryPalette('blue')
    .accentPalette('orange');
    })
    .controller('ctrl',function($scope){
        $scope.buttons={
          left:false,
          middle:false,
          right:false
         };
        var keys=Object.keys($scope.buttons);
        $scope.radioModel='middle';

        $scope.save=function(id){
            $scope.radioModel=keys[id];
        };

  });
```

HTML

```
 <section layout="row">
     <md-input-container>
       <input type="text" ng-model="radioModel"></input>
     </md-input-container>
 </section>
 <section layout="row">
  <md-button ng-click="save('0')" class="md-raised md-primary">left</md-button>
  <md-button ng-click="save('1')" class="md-raised md-primary">middle</md-button>
  <md-button ng-click="save('2')" class="md-raised md-primary">right</md-button> 
 </section>
```

Answer (score 9):

@Bartłomiej As explained in the documentation... As of V 1.0.5 
[Grouping with CSS Overrides](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/CSS/button) (scroll all the way down).

You can just add custom classes to override the theme and achieve the same result.

@nitin, I checked your Plunker and it was missing some CSS, for example the css in the example from the documentation works, see below, or check my [forked Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/GDyddxJbUyeq1o5TA8UM/):

```
.md-button.left {
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
.md-button.middle {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.96);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.96);
}
.md-button.right {
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
.md-button:not([disabled]):hover {
    background-color: rgba(193, 193, 193, 0.96);
    color: rgba(44, 65, 164, 0.96);
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```